# representing list of tuples as 2d array in python

Tags: python

Say I have a list of tuples containing the RGB information of each pixels in an image from left to right, top to bottom.

```
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,4),(9,2,1),(1,1,1),(3,4,5)]
```

Assuming the width and height of the image is already know, is there a way I can represent the image using list of list?

For example, let's say the above list of tuples represent a 2x3 image, `image[1][2]` should give me the RGB tuple `(3,4,5)`.

Comment: `image[x][y]` => `input_list[x * width + y]`. `[1][2]` becomes `[1 * 3 + 2]`.

Comment: So what you're really asking is how to convert a 1d list to a 2d list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `step` argument in [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) (or [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)):

```
>>> width = 2
>>> pixels = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,4),(9,2,1),(1,1,1),(3,4,5)]
>>> image = [pixels[x:x+width] for x in range(0,len(pixels),width)]
>>> image
[[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)], [(1, 2, 4), (9, 2, 1)], [(1, 1, 1), (3, 4, 5)]]
```

It will make `x` increment by the value of the `step`, instead of the default, which is 1. If you are familiar with Java, it's similar to:

```
for (int x=0; x<length; x = x+step)
```